# convert number of bits in subnet mask to dotted decimal form in java

Tags: java, ip

I need to convert the IP Subnet Mask like say 24 to 255.255.255.0 or say 23 to 255.255.254.0 in Java. Is there any API that I can use ?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without any libraries :

```
int cidrMask = 23;
long bits = 0;
bits = 0xffffffff ^ (1 << 32 - cidrMask) - 1;
String mask = String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (bits & 0x0000000000ff000000L) >> 24, (bits & 0x0000000000ff0000) >> 16, (bits & 0x0000000000ff00) >> 8, bits & 0xff);

>>255.255.254.0
```

*Have to use a long because of missing unsigned types in Java*

Comment: I love how compact this is. Stick all that code in a method  

`public String cidrToMask(int cidr) {...}`

add a potato, some carrots, and baby, you've got a stew!

Comment: gma thanks for the compact code. But i have a question when the cidrMask is 0 what will be the subnet mask in dotted decimal form. will it be 0.0.0.0 or 255.255.255.255 ?

Comment: you can try :) : `255.255.255.255`

Comment: gma : On searching online I found that  cidrMask 0 corresponds to 0.0.0.0 and not 255.255.255.255. I just checked on Wikipedia as well   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route (checkout the References)

Answer (score 0):

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/commons/net/util/SubnetUtils.html

I followed NeplatnyUdaj's comment, and it looks like you can construct a SubnetUtils object to get the mask:

```
    int mask = 3;
    String cidr = "255.255.255.255/" + mask;
    SubnetUtils subnet = new SubnetUtils(cidr);

    String stringMask = subnet.getInfo().getNetmask();

    System.out.println("The subnet mask is: " + stringMask);
```

That's what I used, and it worked for me. Infact, using the getNetmask() method makes the IP string you use to construct the cidr String arbitrary.